# Solr pdf indexing -only does some content

Tags: pdf, solr

I have a pdf document that I am trying to index using the solr cell. I use the following command:

```
 curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?   stream.file=/home/Desktop/DOCUMENTS/x.pdf&stream.contentType=application/pdf&literal.id=DOC_N&commit=true"
```

The problem is that when I do a search ":" i see that it has indexed only the TOC in the text field. 
The content of the document is not indexed. I am fairly new to solr and have no idea why this would happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the document text is bigger than `<maxFieldLength>` You could try changing the `<maxFieldLength>` to something higher in solrconfig.xml then reindex.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#mainIndex_Section